# How to handle standard toast events in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

For lightning I used a handler for `force:showToast` event to capture toasts for edit/new actions on standard pop up when a record was edited/inserted. I would like to do the same in lwc.

I added a listener in the constructor and it works well only for my custom toasts, but doesn't work for standard toasts when I open a standard pop up. **Is there a way to capture standard toasts in lwc?**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    document.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', this.handleToastEvent.bind(this))
}

handleToastEvent (){
    console.log('toast')
}
```

Pop up is opened through NavigationMixin.Navigate

```
handleEditRecord(row) {
  this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__recordPage',
      attributes: {
          'recordId': row.Id,
          'actionName': 'edit'
      },
  })
}
```

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/lwc.events_handling), to programmatically register your event listener you need to do the following in your "parent" LWC (an ancestor of the LWC generating the show toast event):

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.template.addEventListener('lightning__showtoast', this.handleToastEvent.bind(this));
}
```

I tried this in a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/3dhgtdkS/1/edit) but the playground doesn't appear to correctly support toasts. It therefore looks like an exercise for the OP to see if this works.

I would assume you would need to provide a component that wraps all the others (perhaps via a "slot") in the page in order to catch "standard" toasts from these components, but I don't think you can catch toasts from the "chrome" of the page outside the body content.

Comment: I have only 1 component, so it is already parent. I tried your code, but standard toast event was not captured.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: If there's only one component that is "already the parent" then adding the event listener around the whole template *should* mean you can capture the toast events from any embedded standard components. If this isn't working you could consider ensuring that the "parent" component includes a div or something similar as a child of the outer-most template that contains everything else, and add the event listener to that element instead.